# Component not rendered unless refreshed in Angular 6+

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

After an authentication, the app redirects to a dashboard. This dashboard has a sidebar and all the router links changes the path name in the address bar but not rendering the component unless the page is manually reloaded.

this is my main `app.component.html` code:

```
<div *ngIf="isLogged" class="dashboard">
    <app-navbar></app-navbar>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row navbar-expand-md">

            <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>

            <main role="main" class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 pt-3 px-4">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom">
                    <h1 class="h2">Dashboard</h1>
                </div>

                <router-outlet></router-outlet>

            </main>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div *ngIf="!isLogged" class="plain-page">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

and this is the `app.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthguardService } from './services/authguard.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

  title = 'App';

  isLogged: boolean = false;
  constructor (
    private router: Router,
    private authguardService: AuthguardService
  ){}

  ngOnInit(){

    // this.isLogged = this.authguardService.canActivate();

    this.authguardService.authStatus.subscribe(
      (data: boolean) => {
        this.isLogged = data;
      }
    );
  }

}
```

Now this is my `router.module`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthguardService as Authguard } from './services/authguard.service';

import { LoginComponent } from './pages/login/login.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './pages/signup/signup.component';
import { UsersComponent } from './pages/users/users.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './pages/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { Google2FAComponent } from './pages/google2-fa/google2-fa.component';
import { RolesComponent } from './pages/roles/roles.component';
import { FileUploadComponent } from './pages/merchant/file-upload/file-upload.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'signup',
    component: SignupComponent
  },
  { 
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'dashboard',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'google2fa/:id',
    component: Google2FAComponent,
    canActivate: [Authguard]
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    canActivate: [Authguard]
  },
  {
    path: 'users',
    component: UsersComponent,
    canActivate: [Authguard]
  },
  {
    path: 'roles',
    component: RolesComponent,
    canActivate: [Authguard]
  },
  {
    path: 'file-upload',
    component: FileUploadComponent,
    canActivate: [Authguard]
  }

]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'})
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class RoutesModule { }
```

And this is the `AuthguardService`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { TokenService } from './token.service';

import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthguardService implements CanActivate {

  private isLoggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(this.tokenService.loggedIn());
  authStatus = this.isLoggedIn.asObservable()

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private tokenService: TokenService
  ) {}


  canActivate(): boolean {
    if (!this.tokenService.loggedIn()) {
      this.router.navigate(['login']);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  changeAuthStatus(value: boolean){

    this.isLoggedIn.next(value);

  }

}
```

What is the problem why the components were not rendered after logging in and needs to be manually reloaded for it to be rendered?

Comment: What's your this.authguardService.authStatus? does the subscribe occurs?

Comment: @moi_meme I have edited and included the `AuthguardService` code. And yes the subscription occurs

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem here might be that due to the Angular Component Lifecycle, the suscribe is never resolving because the component is not shown at the very beginning, please include the following in the constructor:

```
 export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

 title = 'App';

 isLogged: boolean = false;
 constructor (
   private router: Router,
private authguardService: AuthguardService
 ){
   this.authguardService.authStatus.subscribe(
     (data: boolean) => {
         this.isLogged = data;
        }
}

// remove the subscribe from the ngOnInit()
```

Comment: I have tried this but same result. I have updated my question with my `AuthguardService` code.

Comment: @Jay. Try removing this.<div *ngIf="!isLogged" class="plain-page">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>. Your resolver should guard your component. So it does not matter what the route is, angular will reroute it defined by your resolver. Hope this helps.